# MVC5 Membership Provider GetUserId()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen *similar* posts on this, but none have given me an answer I can actually get to work.

I've modified the AuthConfig.cs file to allow for OAuth registration.

I'm definitely logged in and authorized, yet still cannot retrieve the UserId.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // returns true
        var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName(); // returns rory
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // returns null

        return View();
    }
```

Why does this keep returning null? I've used this in other projects many times before and have never had an issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you change the default key type of IdentityUser?

Comment: No, but I was looking at the AccountModel and noticed they retrieved the Id another way and I got it to work. I'm a little confused to say the least... `WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below way of retrieving the Id works while the one in the question does not. I have not seen this before, nor have I seen it in any of the other answers.

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

Successfully returns the UserId, whether or not it is an OAuth or local account.

Answer (score 0):

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
```